# How to change the list to the list of the lists?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to multiply such lists in Python:

```
list1 = [[0.41415110829800006], [0.41415110829800006], [0.41415110829800006]]

list2 = [[0.0, 0.051098245984563244, 0.0]]
```

I want to list2 looks like:

```
list2  = [[0.0], [0.051098245984563244], [0.0]]
```

so I could muliply them using

```
m = [a*b for x,y in zip(list1,list2) for a,b in zip(x,y)]
```

Could you please tell me how to do it in best way?

Comment: Does list1 have anything to do with the question?  The answers show its inclusion (if not relevant) is confusing some responders.  It is encouraged to [show minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list2` is already list of lists, use the first index

```
list2 = [[x] for x in list2[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below instead of building up another list object

```
[list1[i][0] * list2[0][i] for i in range(min(len(list1), len(list2[0])))]
```

you don't have to use the "min" if length of both lists is always same

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are looking for,

```
In [37]: [[l1[0] * ll2] for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2) for ll2 in l2]
Out[37]: [[0.0], [0.0211623952065907], [0.0]]
```